# Expand div come back to original position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, expand

I make an expandable div and now I want that when I click on the close button, the div come back to the original position is it possible to make it when my close button is inside the div containing my open button? That look not logical but how can I do it ? ( with or without my close button inside the div )

There is my code:

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
$('.intro').hide();
$('.content').animate({width: "500px",}, 500);
    setTimeout(function(){
 $('.content').animate({top: "-400px", marginBottom: "0px", height:"1000px"}, 500);
    },500);
   
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.button').find('a').show();
        $('.content').find('.full').show();      
    },1000);
});
```

```css
.button{
  margin-top:20px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  cursor:pointer;
  }


.content{
 position:absolute;
 width:250px;
 height:100px;
 overflow:hidden;
 background:red;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-230px;
 margin-top:-115px;
}

.button a{
 text-align:left;
 color:grey;
 background:none;
 margin-left:0px;
 display:none;
}

.full{ margin-top:600px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"><a class="close_btn"><p>X</p></a>button</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="intro">intro</div>
    <div class="full">full text lorem ipsum ....
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a event listener for your close button, and have it change your div back to it's default values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out. I have modified your code a bit. You dont need to use `setTimeout` because we can make use of the callback function that `.animate` provides.

```
var box = $('.content');
var position = {
    width: box.width(),
    height: box.height(),
    top: box.css('top'),
    left: box.css('left')
}
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('.intro').hide();
    $('.content').animate({
        width: "500px",
        top: "-400px", 
        marginBottom: "0px", 
        height:"1000px"
    }, 500, function(){
         $('.button').find('a').show();
         box.find('.full').show();
    });
})

$('.close_btn').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.button').find('a').hide();
    box.animate({
        top: position.top,
        height: position.height,
        width: position.width
    });

});
```

Here is the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/of8znvc5/5/

Comment: Can you explain? Whehn you click the close button, isnt it coming to its original position

Comment: How can i set it if i have two button for expand the same div with different size of width, i mean one expand on left side , and the other one on the right side, with a button1 and a button2